# Django: Django QuerySet with Date SELECT working erratically

Tags: python, django, date, django-queryset

Up until a couple days ago I have been using the following query succesfully.  The following query has always returned the data it was supposed to return:

```
try:
  totals = MyObject.objects.get(date=report_date)
except MyObject.DoesNotExist:
  return HttpResponse('Could not find totals from %s' % (report_date))
```

A couple days ago this query began returning an empty QuerySet, even though data Does exist for the day I am requesting.

I am getting the date from `report_date = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`
or from a form

```
if request.method == 'POST':
  form = DateForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid:
    report_date = request.POST['date']
```

The Model is simple datefield()

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
  """Total numbers for a specific day"""
  date = models.DateField()
  ... remaining fields ...
```

I have verified through the shell that there is in fact data for todays date in TotalTransactions.  I have been using this code for months with no problem.  I made a work around yesterday by querying 
`totals = MyObject.objects.get(date__gte=report_date, date__lte=report_date)` 
but this morning it no longer worked!! This morning I then tried the original query of `date=report_date` and that worked!

So my question is: Has anyone had this problem before?? Can anyone see something in my code that i am missing? Any suggestions on more workarounds? I appreciate your time.

Comment: I think this is actually an issue with corrupted db data.  This query is too simple not to work, i'm going to look into it today.

Comment: From your sql shell or by using raw sql from python/django code, can you write a simple query to retrieve this item by date?

Comment: one more thought, maybe the issue is with your locale - when you have strings (not date object) system locale is important

Comment: Which database backend are you using? I have seen some issues with date conversion in sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why converting to the string? you do not have a control on how date is converted, eg. locale issues.

switch to `date` objects and set in views only:

```
report_date = date.today()
```

and get data from the form's `cleaned_data` dict:

```
report_date = form.cleaned_data['date']
```

Comment: Thank you, thats better practice, i've tried both a date obj and a string.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that date-based queries work one day but not the next is suggestive. I suspect - although you haven't shown enough code to be sure - that you have inadvertently set some defaults somewhere, which are being persisted across requests.

For example, if you do this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_date_field = model.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
```

the value of the field default is evaluated when the server process starts, and remains the same as long as the process is running - which can be days or weeks.

The same is true if you do this in a view:

```
def my_view(request, date=datetime.date.today()):
    ... do something with date ...
```

because view arguments, again, are evaluated when the view is defined, not when it is executed, and therefore the value will remain the same as long as the process exists.

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default You could pass the function instead of calling it if that's the case for the model. `default=datetime.date.today`